# Matlab programming solution

Tags: matlab, equation

How to solve a equation
  `17.7*sin(A)*cos(A)+87*sin^2(A)-9.65*cos(A)-47*sin(A)=0` using MATLAB ?
I want the value of A satisfying the above equation. I tried using the solve command but it is continuously giving error.

Comment: please post the code you tired with `solve` and the specific error it gave you

Answer (score 4):

Of course it has a solution, it has an infinite number of solutions,  for example you can see graphically that A crosses zero many times in the -4pi to 4pi interval:

```
A=linspace(-4*pi,4*pi,1000);
plot(A,17.7.*sin(A).*cos(A)+87.*sin(A).^2-9.65*cos(A)-47*sin(A))
```

[image]

Another way to look for solutions is using `fzero` near a point `x0`

```
f=@(A) 17.7.*sin(A).*cos(A)+87.*sin(A).^2-9.65*cos(A)-47*sin(A);
x0=0;
sol = fzero(f,x0)

sol =
   -0.2020
```

For finding multiple roots  on an interval see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809744/equivalent-to-roots-for-non-polynomials-in-matlab).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the [Symbolic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/) is helpful even when you want numeric solutions. The function is periodic between `-pi` and `pi` (or any `2*pi` interval). You can use [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) to find all four roots in this interval:

```
syms A;
s = solve(17.7*sin(A)*cos(A)+87*sin(A)^2-9.65*cos(A)-47*sin(A)==0,A,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true)

>> s = 
     -0.20201862493051844310946374889219
      0.57212820231996826457022742739841
      2.5736433165658736546275270008849
      2.9380144125412806473039849317812
```

When `solve` can't find an analytic solution it [returns a numeric one](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#btrxs35-1). In this case one has to turn on the "simplification rules" via the [`'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#btrwa0u-1) option to force `solve` to return all of the solutions. I'm not sure why this is as this option usually does the opposite.

Use the function `double` to convert symbolic values from `solve` to floating point: `s = double(s);`. You can then add `N*2*pi`, where `N` is an integer, to these four values to obtain the roots of the function in any other interval.