# Is it possible to get several solutions to an arbitrary equation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, equation

Suppose I have a function `f = @(x) myfun(x)`;

I can use [`fzero`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) to get the solution closest to a given `x0`, but can I get all solutions in a specific area, for instance: `-5 < x < 5`?

I.e.
Is it possible to get a solution similar to the result of [`roots`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html), but for non-polynomials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.

There's a nice [submission on the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15122) that allows you to do exactly that. It works by approximating your curve by a Chebychev polynomial, and then finding all real roots of that polynomial.

If you want you can use these estimates for the roots as initial values for `fzero`, but often (at least for smooth and otherwise well-behaved curves) the accuracy demands can already be met by using a higher-order Chebychev approximation.

For your example, using only 18 function evaluations (I have a slightly modified version of the file, but the essence is the same):

```
>> f = @(A) 17.7*sin(A).*cos(A)+87*sin(A).^2-9.65*cos(A)-47*sin(A);
>> R = FindRealRoots(f, -5,5, 17)
R =
  -3.709993256346244
  -3.345207732130925
  -0.201929737187637
   0.572382702285053
   2.573423209113534
   2.937157987217741

>> R2 = R; 
>> funcCount = 0;
>> for ii = 1:numel(R) 
        [R2(ii), ~,~, output]  = fzero(f,R2(ii)); 
        funcCount = funcCount + output.funcCount;
   end
>> max(abs(R2(:)-R(:)))
ans =
    8.564253235401331e-004
>> funcCount
ans = 
    46
```

e.g., there is only 8 parts per ten thousand improvement for no less than 46 additional function evaluations.

Comment: @RobertP.: None that I know of...which is somewhat strange, since [Chebychev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) are the best choice for polynomial approximations. Indeed, at least for the type of function you're dealing with (smooth, continuous, etc.), accuracy can  be expected to be pretty high. The only drawback with it is that it can be difficult to choose 'good' values of `n` (this is where that built-in plotting function comes in handy).

Comment: +1 for suggesting Chebychev polynomials, I found them very useful in many aspects of computation.

Answer (score 2):

First there is Matlab's built in option that uses the symbolic math toolbox:  [mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-realroots.html](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-realroots.html)

Another option, if your function is well behaved, is just to feed `fsolve` with the right guesses, so even though it is using a loop, it is an efficient computation. For example:

```
A=linspace(-5,5,1000);
f=@(A) 17.7.*sin(A).*cos(A)+87.*sin(A).^2-9.65*cos(A)-47*sin(A)

idx = find(diff(sign(f(A))));
for n=1:numel(idx)
    r(n)=fzero(f,A(idx(n)))
end

r=
  -3.709541990613713
  -3.345170894638306
  -0.202018624930518
   0.572128202319968
   2.573643316565874
   2.938014412541281
```

Comment: Thanks @natan! I didn't know about `numeric::realroots`. The second solution was nice too! =)