# Matlab: Fsolve function and all possible roots

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB's `fsolve` function to solve systems of nonlinear equations. I have two nonlinear equations with two variables `(x,y);`

I'm trying to find the all possible roots for the both variables. I noted that the `fsolve`  gives just one root. How it possible to get the **all roots** for the equations?

My code as the following:

```
function F = fun(guess)
    x = guess(1); 
    y = guess(2);

    F = [2*x -y - exp(-x));
        -x + 2*y - exp(-y) ];
end
```

call the function:

```
guess = [-5 -5]
fsolve(@fun,guess);
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809744/equivalent-to-roots-for-non-polynomials-in-matlab). I think you can modify [Rody's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16809955/2338750), by changing the second and third input variables.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that there is only one root, so you don't need to search further.

From the second equation,

```
  -x + 2·y - exp(-y) = 0
⇒ x = 2·y - exp(-y)
```

Substitute `x` into the first equation:

```
  2·x - y - exp(-x) = 0
⇒ 2·(2y-exp(-y)) - y - exp(-(2y-exp(-y)) = 0
```

which is a function of `y` only. Standard calculus will show this `f(y)` is monotonically increasing, starts negative at `y=-∞` and is positive at `y=+∞`. The result is the same for when you do the substitution the other way around. This implies there is only 1 simultaneous root to both equations.

QED.

Comment: This is just an example ... I'm dealing with two nonlinear equations with degrees 8 and 6 ... I did not write the two equations because they are complicated. anyway; my question was : is it possible to use fsolve to find all possible roots of nonlinear equations!. and if not; what is the alternative method to solve such nonlinear equations.

Comment: @CS2013: Then, in the future, also include the comment that you are using dummy equations. You made it sound like *this* was your problem.

Comment: @CS2013: In any case, if you only have 2 equations, you can still do something similar (although I'd start using the symbolic math toolbox then). Solve 1 equation in terms of the other and find the roots of that function. Do it the other way around, too. The roots common to both are the answer.

Comment: @CS2013: Or: all roots thus found can serve as starting points to subsequent calls to `fsolve`.

Comment: @CS2013: If it is not possible to isolate the `x` and `y` in either equation, then as far as I can see, there is not much more you can do then do a brute-force grid search. That is, restart `fsolve` many times for many different starting values (possibly assisted by 2D plots of the equations, of course).

Comment: Thanks Rody Oldenhuis  for help. It's very difficult to isolate the x and y in either equation.
Check this link: [equations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633920/solve-nonlinear-equations-variables-with-degree-six-and-degree-eight)

Answer (score 0):

`fsolve` is not a global solver. There are global solvers (like genetic algorithms and simulated annealing), but they have to run for an infinite amount of time to guarantee that the returned solutions comprise all of the minimizers. On the hand, almost all other optimization solvers are local, meaning that they will only guarantee that a local minimizer is returned.

Furthermore, in addition to not knowing whether the returned solution is a global or local minimizer, there is, in general, no way of determining how many roots a problem has. So basically, there is no way of doing what you want except for 2 well known cases:

1) If the problem is convex, then there are no local minimizers that are not global minimizers. So anything returned by fsolve will be a global minimizer. Furthermore, this minimizer is almost always unique. The exception is that technically, there can exist an infinite number of solutions, but they will all be connected (like on a specific plane). There cannot exist a finite number of distinct minimizers that are not connected.

2) Polynomials have a distinct number of roots that we can uniquely determine.