# Use Matlab/Maple to find roots of a nonlinear equation

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, maple, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions

I am having difficulty in finding roots of a nonlinear equation. I have tried Matlab and Maple both, and both give me the same error which is

```
Error, (in RootFinding:-NextZero) can only handle isolated zeros
```

The equation goes like

```
-100 + 0.1335600000e-5*H + (1/20)*H*arcsinh(2003.40/H)
```

The variable is `H` in the equation.

How do I find the roots (or the approximate roots) of this equation?

Matlab Code:
The function file:

```
function hor_force = horizontal(XY, XZ, Lo, EAo, qc, VA)
syms H
equation = (-1*ZZ) + (H/qc)*(cosh((qc/H)*(XZ- XB))) - H/qc + ZB;
hor_force = `solve(equation);`
```

The main file:

```
EAo = 7.5*10^7;
Lo = 100.17;
VA = 2002;

XY = 0;
ZY = 0;

XB = 50;
ZB = -2;

XZ = 100;
ZZ = 0;

ql = 40;
```

Error which Matlab shows:

```
Error using sym/solve (line 22)
Error using maplemex
Error, (in RootFinding:-NextZero) can only handle isolated zeros

Error in horizontal (line 8)
hor_force = solve(equation);
Error in main (line 34)
h = horizontal(XY, XZ, Lo, EAo, ql, VA)
```

http://postimg.org/image/gm93z3b7z/

Comment: Works fine for me in Matlab R2014b. What `version` are you using? Is that the actual code that produced the error? Please edit to show the full error message in Matlab.

Comment: The parameters provided definitely don't correspond to those in the equation as the top.

Comment: @horchler Yes, this is the same code that I am using. I am using Matlab 2013b. I have posted the error message that Matlab is showing. Please help.

Comment: @horchler I am sorry, I posted the parameters of some other problem of the same type. I have edited it though. Can you please recheck?

Comment: The `maplemex` in the error is interesting. I'm very surprised that there's anything left of Maple in Matlab's Symbolic Math toolbox. What do you get when you type `symengine` in the command window? Are you possibly using an old version of the toolbox with R2013b?

Comment: @horchler 'Undefined' function or the variable. Here is the image. I am not really sure about the version. http://postimg.org/image/qfew6d087/

Comment: You're clearly using a very old version of the Symbolic Math toolbox that is not current with your Matlab version (or since you have Maple installed, maybe that program injected it's own toolbox on top of Matlab's). Type `ver` in the command window and look for the version number of the "Symbolic Math Toolbox" - for R2013b, it should say 5.11 (R2013b).

Comment: Yesm it's an old version. Thanks. I will have to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the symbolic toolbox for this:

First, create an anonymous function that can take vectors at input (use `.*` and `./`:

```
equation = @(H) ((-1*ZZ) + (H./qc).*(cosh((qc./H).*(XZ- XB))) - H./qc + ZB);
```

Second, create a vector that you afterwards insert into the equation to find approximately when the sign of the function changes. In the end, use [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) with `x0` as the second input parameter.

```
H = linspace(1,1e6,1e4);  
x0 = H(find(diff(sign(equation(H)))));  %// Approximation of when the line crosses zero
x = fzero(equation, x0)  %// Use fzero to find the crossing point, using the initial guess x0
x =    
   2.5013e+04
equation(x)
ans =
     0
```

To verify:

[image]

You might want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809744/equivalent-to-roots-for-non-polynomials-in-matlab) for more information about how to find roots of non-polynomials.

Comment: FYI, as this function is monotonically decreasing and only has a single real root on the positive axis, the `x0 = H(find(diff(sign(equation(H)))));` code to find an initial guess is unnecessary and very inefficient. `fzero` has very efficient code for bracketing the root in such cases.  Or you could set `x0 = [1 1e6];`, the bound on your `linspace` call, and again, it will tightly bracket the root, by splitting the domain in two successively, in many many fewer iterations than `1e4`.

Answer (score 0):

In Maple, using the expression from your question,

```
restart:

ee := -100 + 0.1335600000e-5*H + (1/20)*H*arcsinh(2003.40/H):

Student:-Calculus1:-Roots(ee, -1e6..1e6);

            [               5                           ]
            [-1.240222868 10 , -21763.54830, 18502.23816]

#plot(ee, H=-1e6..1e6, view=-1..1);
```