# Nonlinear root finding in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

```
function y = f(z)

b=10;


y=(cos(z))+(b*(sin(z)/z))-cos(d);
```

This is my function file.

```
fun = @f; % function

x0 = 1; % initial point  

z = fzero(fun,x0);
```

While running above code I am getting only a single value. But What I need is a set of values satisfying

```
(cos(z))+(b*(sin(z)/z))-cos(d)=0
```

Where: d=-5:1:5

Please kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different initial points. This process can be automated:

```
solutions= zeros(1,100);
for k= 1:numel(solutions)
    x0= (rand-0.5)*20; % generate the random initial point in (-10,10)
    z = fzero(@f,x0);
    solutions(k)= z;
end
disp(unique(solutions))
```

The result can include identical solutions due to the solver accuracy.

Another way to find the initial points [is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27183928/6282716)

Comment: Really thankful for your extraordinary brilliant answer. Shall I ask 1 more question.

Comment: y=(cos(z))+(b*(sin(z)/z))-1         Here instead of 1 I have cos(d) where: d=2*pi*[-5:1:5];     Then how can I modify the same